# Multiple RewriteRule error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I never used .httacces and i'm stuck in a RewriteRule problem
I want to build pagination in a directory and I don't see the code error or what i'm doing wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z+A-Z0-9_-]+)$ categ.php?categ=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ subcateg.php?subcateg=$2&categ=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ list.php?id=$3
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/page=(.*)$ subcateg.php?subcateg=$2&categ=$1&page=3
```

I added the last row and it's not working.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ categ.php?categ=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/page=(.*)$ subcateg.php?subcateg=$2&categ=$1&page=3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)$ subcateg.php?subcateg=$2&categ=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ list.php?id=$3 [L]
```